# Android Studio Flutter Failure with Gradle Exception

Tags: android-studio, flutter, gradle

I am running this on macOS 10.15.5 Catalina. I recently was able to run this application within the quemu e86 emulator, but recently I have been having issues and now I get odd Gradle errors.

I will preface this by stating that my flutter is completely fubar'd and no matter how many times I add the path to my .bash_profile I am not able to run flutter doctor or anything related to flutter within terminal. Trust me, I have looked through numerous other articles to try to figure this out but thus far I've had no luck.

```
    Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:88:26: Error: Type 'DiagnosticableMixin' not found.
class PictureStream with DiagnosticableMixin {
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:192:44: Error: Type 'DiagnosticableMixin' not found.
abstract class PictureStreamCompleter with DiagnosticableMixin {
                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:88:7: Error: The type 'DiagnosticableMixin' can't be mixed in.
class PictureStream with DiagnosticableMixin {
      ^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:192:16: Error: The type 'DiagnosticableMixin' can't be mixed in.
abstract class PictureStreamCompleter with DiagnosticableMixin {
               ^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:167:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'debugFillProperties'.
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:171:30: Error: The method 'toStringShort' isn't defined for the class 'PictureStreamCompleter'.
 - 'PictureStreamCompleter' is from 'package:flutter_svg/src/picture_stream.dart' ('../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toStringShort'.
      ifPresent: _completer?.toStringShort(),
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:266:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'debugFillProperties'.
    super.debugFillProperties(description);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/edperez/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 896

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/edperez/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 36s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I am losing my mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There may be an error in your flutter cache. run these in your terminal and see if they can help you:

```
flutter pub cache repair 
flutter clean
```

Comment: Hey @P4yam, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, as my flutter is probably very VERY messed up at the moment, my bash window only spits out `-bash: flutter: command not found`

Comment: Also, I will say that I changed the name of one of the other users on the Mac I'm using. It it possible that this royally messed something up with my flutter install or what have you. I created a new admin for myself through Users & Groups in Sys...Prefs.app but that shouldn't affect things too much, right y'all?

Comment: @EduardoPerez I had the same problem before on my linux system. the last thing you can do is completely removing flutter and dart then installing it again.